# Creating a Drop Down Menu Bar in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, awt, menuitem

I'm practicing creating a GUI program in Java using swing and awt imports. Most everything in my main class is working, except for getting a drop-down menu with a tab named file at the top of the GUI. I have two snippets of code, one in the JPanel class and the other in the public main() class. I ultimately want to get a file menu with save and save as options at the top. Don't need to invoke anything or add listeners, just to make them visible on the program itself. I'm using JMenuBar menuBar along with JMenu fileMenu to create it. What am I doing wrong? Snippets below:

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenuItem saveItem, saveAllItem;
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
```

---

```
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    saveItem = fileMenu.add("Save");
    saveAllItem = fileMenu.add("Save All");
    panel.add(menuItem);

    setVisible(true);
```

Comment: `panel.add(menuItem);` looks wrong. You should be adding the `fileMenu` to the `menuBar` and the `saveItem` and `saveAllItem` to the `fileMenu`

Comment: Maybe take a closer look at [How to use menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any need of adding JMenuBar object to JPanel because it is only linked with the JFrame. 
You need to pass the JMenuBar object to JFrame method **setJMenuBar()** in order to set the menu bar in the window.
You can create a drop down menu for JFrame by using this code:

```
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenuItem saveItem, saveAllItem;

    // Menu
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

    // Menu Item (Drop down menus)
    saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
    saveAllItem = new JMenuItem("Save All");

    // Adding menu items to menu
    fileMenu.add(saveItem);
    fileMenu.add(saveAllItem);

    // adding menu to menu bar
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);

    // setting menubar at top of the window.

    // if you create a object of JFrame in class then code to set JMenuBar to JFrame will be:
    // jframe.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    // if class is extending JFrame then it will be like this:
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```